# Youtube API AS3 - Is it possible to only have two buttons control the Stop/Play and Mute/Unmute of YouTube video

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube

Below is the AS3 code taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQnoOcPbgx0. Currently there are 5 buttons. I would like the –

- btnPlay to control both the player.playVideo(); and the player.pauseVideo();
- btnMute to control both the player.mute(); and player.unMute();
- buttons to appear on rollover only

You can view a demo here (rollover left orange button to view video) http://pages.areadevelopment.com/advertisers/MDA/index.html

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you! CE

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.MouseCursor;

Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var player:Object;


var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onInit);
loader.x = 344;    
loader.y = 34;

function onInit(e:Event):void{

    addChild(loader);

    player = loader.content;

    player.addEventListener("onReady",onPlayerReady);

}

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{

    player.setSize(330,225);

    player.loadVideoById("nHnXVBNizDQ",0);  

}

btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVid);

    function playVid(e:MouseEvent):void{

    player.playVideo();

}

btnPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVid);

function pauseVid(e:MouseEvent):void{

    player.pauseVideo();

}

btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopVid);

function stopVid(e:MouseEvent):void{

    player.stopVideo();

}

btnMute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteVid);

function muteVid(e:MouseEvent):void{

    player.mute();

}

btnUnmute.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, UnmuteVid);

function UnmuteVid(e:MouseEvent):void{

    player.unMute();

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pay a freelancer to do the job for you, as you haven't tried anything yourself, and aren't in need of help with your code. StackOverflow is not a "make code for me please" site.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to give that impression. I am not a coder, have searched extensively for this and have not found where I can combine the two functions  in one button - thought it had to do with the fact that it was a YouTube video.